# Adding comments to Example Value in Swagger UI

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I am trying to get summary comments from my code into the example value field in Swagger UI. However, the comments are only visible in the Schema field. Is there a way to include the comments in the example value as well (e.g. as an extra parameter or an extra line)? I am using just a basic Weather Forecast template code with Swashbuckle.

This is my GET endpoint:

```
        [HttpGet("weather")]
        [Produces("application/vnd.ms-excel")]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
          ...
        }
```

This is my model:

```
    /// <summary>
    ///     Object containing the weather forecast data.
    /// </summary>
    public class WeatherForecast
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///     Date of the forecast.
        /// </summary>
        /// <example>01/01/2022 12:00:00</example>
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Temperature in Celsius.
        /// </summary>
         /// <example>20</example>>
        public int TemperatureC { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Temperature in Fahrenheit.
        /// </summary>
        /// <example>68</example>
        public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int) (TemperatureC / 0.5556);

        /// <summary>
        ///     Summary of the forecast.
        /// </summary>
        /// <example>Chilly</example>
        public string? Summary { get; set; }
    }
```

And this is my Swagger config:

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.IncludeXmlComments(string.Format(@"{0}MyAPIProject.xml",AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory));
    c.ExampleFilters();
});
```

Comment: Hi @Tomáš Zajda, when i use your code and it will generate the `Example` with the `<example>` value and generate the `Schema` with both `<example>` and `<summary>`. Do you want to display the `<summary>` in  `Example`?

Comment: Hello, yes that is exactly the goal, to have summary in the example value.

Answer (score 1):

try adding this according to the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

```
 <PropertyGroup>
        <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
        <NoWarn>$(NoWarn);1591</NoWarn>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I have done that, unfortunately it doesn't help. I was thinking the solution might be some kind of custom formatter or something like that, but I wasn't able to find any solutions online.

Comment: once you get the solution please share it with us coz I am interested to find out

Comment: I definitely will if I manage to find some!